# Is it possible to turn off antialiasing when using ImageBrush tiling?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, antialiasing, imagebrush

Is it possible to turn off anti-aliasing in WPF when using an ImageBrush?

Given the following code:

```
var handleImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri($"pack://application:,,,/Resources/myimage.png"));
var imageBrush = new ImageBrush(handleImage);
imageBrush.AlignmentY = AlignmentY.Top;
imageBrush.AlignmentX = AlignmentX.Left;
imageBrush.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
imageBrush.Viewport = new Rect(0, 0, _handleImage.Width, _handleImage.Height);
imageBrush.ViewportUnits = BrushMappingMode.Absolute;
imageBrush.TileMode = TileMode.Tile;
drawingContext.DrawRectangle(imageBrush, null, new Rect(0, 0, width, height));
```

Gives me something like: [image: WPF Output]

But I'm expecting: [image: Expected Output]

WPF's default antialiasing makes it look terrible. I've tried `UseLayoutRounding=true`, `SnapsToDevicePixels=true`, `RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(this, BitmapScalingMode.HighQuality)`,
`RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(this, BitmapScalingMode.NearestNeighbor)` `RenderOptions.SetEdgeMode(this, EdgeMode.Unspecified);` on the window. The only one that changes any visual difference is `BitmapScalingMode.NearestNeighbor` however it still looks odd and the tiling overlaps itself.

EDIT: Download full working sample: [WpfImageBrushExample.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CzGniHbipIs84lmQUrsZrqPPPyJ6oAih/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Trying this just now, I don't see any problem, which suggests it's something else you haven't included. I would try setting `RenderOptions.EdgeMode` to `EdgeMode.Alias`, and if that doesn't work try posting an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Yup I can do that - I’ve also tried setting that as well but none of the options seem to affect the brush

Comment: @MarkFeldman Full example added showing the drawing on any of the specified options mentioned in the post.

Comment: The problem was two-fold: The `_handleImage` dimensions are supposed to be 4 x 5 but was returned as `5.333 x 6.66`. I need to use PixelWidth x PixelHeight and not Width x Height. Second, the `NearestNeighbor` scaling mode solves the problem once that is fixed! I'll answer my own question

Comment: Glad to hear you solved it. And thanks for posting what it was, I wouldn't have thought a non-integer width or height would have done that? Something to keep an eye out for in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that the `BitmapImage` width and height were different fractional numbers - in this case it was `5.333 x 6x666` instead of the expected `4 x 5` pixels. If I use `_handleImage.PixelWidth` and `_handleImage.PixelHeight` the problem is fixed and I don't get weird aliasing under any of those rendering options set.

```cs
var handleImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri($"pack://application:,,,/Resources/myimage.png"));
var imageBrush = new ImageBrush(handleImage);
imageBrush.AlignmentY = AlignmentY.Top;
imageBrush.AlignmentX = AlignmentX.Left;
imageBrush.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
imageBrush.Viewport = new Rect(0, 0, _handleImage.PixelWidth, _handleImage.PixelHeight);
imageBrush.ViewportUnits = BrushMappingMode.Absolute;
imageBrush.TileMode = TileMode.Tile;
drawingContext.DrawRectangle(imageBrush, null, new Rect(0, 0, width, height));
```

Produces: [image: Expected]